# Firebase sw.js not respnding after closing browser

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have created firebase project for using Cloud Messaging   . until now I have sent a message from backend to client successfully when the browser (chrome) is open but when I close the browser notification not sending until reopening of the browser in below code you can see my firebase-messaging-sw.js

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-messaging.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "My-Sender-Id"
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    var notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {
    var data;
    if (e.data) {
        data = JSON.parse(e.data.text()).data;
    } else {
        data = {};
    }
    var title = data.title;
    var options = {
        body: data.body,
        icon: 'assets/custom/img/logo.png',
        vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
        requireInteraction: true,
        data: data.data ? data.data : null,
        dir: "rtl",
        actions: [{
                action: data.action,
                title: 'open',
                icon: 'images/checkmark.png'
            },
            {
                action: 'close',
                title: 'close',
                icon: 'images/xmark.png'
            },
        ]
    };
    e.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
    );
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();
    if (event.action != "" && event.action != "close") {
        return clients.openWindow(event.action);
    }
});
```

how can I have notification even browser is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using service worker for FCM, and the service worker only works when the browser is open ,as service worker is responsible for handling the push notification, when the browser is closed you won't receive any push notification, Actually the push notification will appear only when the browser is opened ,or the application for which you have configured FCM is open on chrome tabs but not focused, there  is one work around or you say solution for it , that is make sure the chrome browser is active in the background  even after closing chrome browser.

There is option in chrome settings

**Goto Settings -> Advanced -> Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed** make sure you enable it 
 [image: Option to Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed]

i have tested the code of FCM , after enabling the   option you will get the notification popup.

Comment: I have checked and enabled this option before but still, I must have to open the browser to get notifications

Comment: can you post the snapshot of how you have registered the service worker

Comment: I use fire-base libs so I don't need to register the service worker firebase-messaging-sw.js register it for me

Comment: can you check whether service worker is successfully registered by lib then, you can check by following the steps ,
make sure you have closed your application, 
open any tab on chrome -> Open Chrome Developers Applicatin tab -> Service Workers -> Service Worker from Other Domains

try and find your firebase service worker in it.
we will know whether is libs is able to register the service worker or not,

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve should be accomplished using a database like firestore. When a notification is received at the time when browser is closed, in the service worker, you should add the code to save the notification message in the firestore so that when user opens the website again, you can retrieve the messages from the firestore and can display them to user. As soon as the browser is opened, any pending notification would be saved to the database by service worker.

I believe this should be the preferred way to achieve this.